# Silent printing functionality for Android & iOS application

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, printing, xamarin.android

I am working on iOS & Android application using Xamarin where I am trying to print implement silent printing functionality currently I am using following Android native scripts which always show dialog during print.

Android print script using Webview:

```
public void Print(WebView viewToPrint)
    {
        var droidViewToPrint = Platform.CreateRenderer(viewToPrint).ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0) as Android.Webkit.WebView;

        if (droidViewToPrint != null)
        {
            // Only valid for API 19+
            var version = Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt;

            if (version >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                var printMgr = (PrintManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PrintService);

                printMgr.Print("Forms-EZ-Print", droidViewToPrint.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter(), null);

            }
        }
    }
```

iOS print script for Text:

```
public void Print()
 {
     var printInfo = UIPrintInfo.PrintInfo;
     printInfo.JobName = "My first Print Job";
     printInfo.OutputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General;

     var textFormatter = new UISimpleTextPrintFormatter("Once upon a time...")
     {
        StartPage = 0,
        MaximumContentWidth = 6 * 72,
        PerPageContentInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(72, 72, 72, 72),
     };

     var printer = UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;
     printer.PrintInfo = printInfo;
     printer.PrintFormatter = textFormatter;
     printer.ShowsPageRange = true;
     printer.Present(true, (handler, completed, error) =>
     {
        if (!completed && error != null)
        {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error.LocalizedDescription ?? ""}");
        }
        });

    printInfo.Dispose();
    textFormatter.Dispose();
}
```

Could please let know how can print silently from iOS and Android application without any print preview or dialog?

Comment: You will need a printer that has an Android/iOS SDK or at the very least accepts a network connection that you can send the data over.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, for your comment. got the idea. I am still looking for an example or document on it. So that I can follow it to accomplish my tasks.

Comment: Any such approach will be printer/manufacturer specific, so you will need to search for an appropriate printer type (e.g. receipt printer)  and find a model/manufacturer with Android & iOS SDKs